# With Typescript in React, make compiler infer property type based on generic provided value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say that I have the following `Props` type

```
type Props<InDashboard extends boolean> = { inDashboard: InDashboard } & (InDashboard extends true
    ? {
          name: string; 
      }
    : { name?: string });
```

As we can see, if `inDashboard` is `true`, name is mandatory, if not, it isn't.

Now, when using the following component:

```
const Dashboard = <InDashboard extends boolean>({ inDashboard, name }: Props<InDashboard>) => {
    const value: string = inDashboard ? name : 'default';

    return <div>{value}</div>;
};
```

I encounter this compiler exception
[image]

Which changes can I make to make the compiler understand that when `inDashboard` is `true`, then `name` does have a value, without adding `as string` or anything similar?

Thanks ☺️

Comment: Have a read: https://kelsny.github.io/typescript/conditional-type-abuse.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need generics to make something like this work. [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) work as well:

```
type DashboardProps = {
    inDashboard: true;
    name: string;
} | {
    inDashboard?: false;
    name?: string;
};

const Dashboard = ({ inDashboard, name }: DashboardProps) => {
    const value: string = inDashboard ? name : 'default';

    return <div>{value}</div>;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCpgE8wk4ARFAZwAsAjCFKAEwAKOMKzgBeOAG8qcWXGAA7Fh268+ALjgwoAVyQVKcuApQgkm1tsUBzAwF84AHyky5i5Vx78A-JswoAG1Z9V1kTM184SygbewMqNAgFS2Y2TzVxOAAKSXklNNV+ABpjU0Y7TQ9CwWFWAEpxAD4XQzlE5PgAN0C9CysFa0z3Aq8+OG9SszhNAHI+JH8dAJgZ+NbZIhgdKAU4AB4+YE7GyW6AvTs9gHpD47iqKj2q0bgrxoMnkYzwpDFJfG4nHwDjeH2e3zKfwBECBDmGKheoMe4P4k1+-0BwLyKL4f38QSQIPeyK+qJ+UMxcPyCLUf20F1exMonxpqPh6X4dN0hMZpFeVzgIGArFYNjRJNZY3Z1V5-MFwtFAzRQA)